# XSD Regex: Capitalize first letter of each word

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

What could be an appropriate regex to capitalize the first letter of each word (separated by spaces) in XML Schema?

(PS: word boundaries dont really work in XSD)

So far, I have this:

```
xs:pattern value="(([A-Z])([a-zA-Z])* (([A-Z])([a-zA-Z])*)*)"
```

But this will somehow require two or more words. The regex should also be able to accept only a single word (with the first letter capitalized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
"[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*( [A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)*"
```